# How to randomly choose true/false w/ weight in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have created a function below that randomly chooses `true` or `false` w/ the chances of each being 50% by default. This function is by no means perfect. How would you refactor this method to make it more concise?

```
def choose(weight = 50)
  bucket = []
  weight.times do
    bucket << true
  end
  while bucket.size < 100
    bucket << false
  end
  bucket.sample
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following implementation is more concise, fast and ruby-like:

```
def choose(weight = 50)
  rand <= weight/100.0
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need only these values (`true`/`false`), it's a little bit easier than picking arbitrary values.

```
def choose(weight = 50)
  chance = rand() # value between 0 and 1
  chance <= weight / 100.0
end

10.times.map{ choose(80)} # => [true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple equivalent of your function (100 discrete buckets)

```
def choose(weight = 50) 
  rand(100) < weight
end
```